# How do I select one record per group and left join with another table?

Tags: mysql

I have one table with two location IDs (pointa and pointb) and how far apart they are. Multiple pairs can be the same distance apart.

Example data:

`pointa pointb distance`

`1       2       250`

`3       4       250`

`4       5       250`

`.....`

`6       8       500`

`10     12       500`

`13     17       500`

I want to select one pair from each distance class (one from 250, one from 500 and so on) and join those to another table which contain attributes for that location.

If I were to write this as an algorithm, it would go:

Select one pair at random from each distance class from table distance
join with table data based on distance.pointa=data.location.
Then do the same for pointb such that pointb=data.location

So after the join, I end up with:

`pointa pointb data_a data_b`

`1       2     234.5   440.2`

Does anyone have ideas on how I can achieve this?

For now I am doing this using PHP (looking up attributes for a, then b, and then updating a new table. Clearly this is inefficient and I want to learn a better way to do this directly in MySQL.

tia.

Answer (score 0):

getting random rows in SQL can be less than efficient.  I'd try something like:

```
SELECT distance, GROUP_CONCAT(pointa) a, GROUP_CONCAT(pointb) b FROM mytable
GROUP BY distance;
```

Then in PHP,

```
while($distance_points= $result->fetch_assoc()){
  $distance=$distance_points['distance'];
  $as=explode($distance_points['a']);
  $random_a=array_rand($as,1);
  $bs=explode($distance_points['b']);
  $random_b=$bs[array_search($as,$random_a)]; //to get the pair assuming points don't repeat

  echo "$distance $random_a $random_b";

}
```

ETA: Since you have too much data for GROUP_CONCAT, a multiquery solution might work better. Something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT distance FROM mytable ORDER BY distance; //get an array with the possible distances

foreach($distances as $d)
  $q="SELECT distance, a, b FROM mytable WHERE distance=$d ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
  //run query, retrieve single result and output or store
}
```

Since you want to get extra info about your locations a and b, you could add that join to `$q`.  Something like:

```
SELECT distance, a, li1.gps, b, li2.gp2
FROM mytable m 
  JOIN location_info li1 ON (m.a=li1.id) 
  JOIN location_info li2 ON (m.b=li2.id) 
WHERE distance=$d 
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I'm grateful that you taught me GROUP_CONCAT. However, it doesn't really help because it grabs all of the pointa's at each distance. For example, I have close to 5000 records for that distance. I want one at random.  If I use your example, I would get all 5000 as a string.

Also, pointa and pointb in a row are meant to denote two points that are a certain distance apart. So in my example, point 1 is exactly 250m from point 2. I thus have to maintain the association between the two. Ideally, I want:

select pointa, pointb, distance from mytable group by distance limit 1 per distinct(distance).

Comment: @Maiasaura: the original solution works by exploding the string into an array, choosing a random member of the array, finding its index and getting the corresponding  location from the 2nd exploded string.  However, there are limits on string length to `GROUP_CONCAT` that make it inappropriate for large amounts of data.  I've added a second solution which requires more queries but is also, perhaps, more straightforward. Keep in mind though, that `ORDER BY RAND()` is slow.